# Add parameter to json based on existing parameter value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
    "data": [{
        "prop": "prop1",
        "template": "template1",
        "group": [{
            "group_name": "Group 1",


        }, {
            "group_name": "Group 2",


        }, {
            "group_name": "Group 3",


        }]
    }]
}
```

In the above json I need push the `group_no` based on `group_name`. i.e. If `group_name` is equal to `Group 1` then `group_no` is equal to `10`. and form the following json. How do I update the existing json?

```
{
    "data": [{
        "prop": "prop1",
        "template": "template1",
        "group": [{
            "group_name": "Group 1",
            "group_no": "10"

        }, {
            "group_name": "Group 2",
            "group_no": "11"

        }, {
            "group_name": "Group 3",
            "group_no": "12"

        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: `How do I update the existing json without looping through it` Unless you know exactly what index each group is positioned at, you need to loop through it.

Comment: A proper way is to use a Json parser/writer. An ugly one is to find each "group_name", jump to the end of the value, and then add ", groupe_no ....". The ugly way isn't safe cause you may get problems in implementation, so prefer to loop through it.

Comment: Why don't you want to loop through it?

Comment: If  I am looping through it then how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way.

```js
var json = {
    "data": [{
        "prop": "prop1",
        "template": "template1",
        "group": [{
            "group_name": "Group 1",


        }, {
            "group_name": "Group 2",


        }, {
            "group_name": "Group 3",


        }]
    }]
};

json.data[0].group.forEach(function(d){ 
  if(d.group_name=="Group 1") 
    d.group_no = 10; 
  else if(d.group_name=="Group 2") 
    d.group_no = 11; 
  else 
    d.group_no = 12; 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by not looping, for you need to loop through it anyway. But what you want is done like this:

```
data[0].group = data[0].group.map(function(el) {
    switch (el.group_name) {
        case 'Group 1': return el.group_no = '10';
        case 'Group 2': return el.group_no = '11';
        ...
        default: return el;
    }
});
```

If your JSON object is actually text, you first to `var parsed = JSON.parse(data);` and work with `parsed` instead of `data`. Afterwords you can `data = JSON.stringify(parsed);`